# Magento 2 : How do redirect to previous page after Registration (Create An Account)?

Tags: magento2, customer, redirect

I want to redirect customer after new registration on referrer page like if the customer is view any specific product and then he clicks for registration then after registration we want to redirect on same page. Its working file for login and I want to do same thing on registration.

How we change the default redirect in case of new registration ?

Comment: going to old page if customer is visit from product? Or all the case.. when customer  from my page before login?

Comment: want to go previous page whatever it is after registration.

Answer (score 1):

Magento2 already have setting by this you can **redirect a customer  to previous page after Registration**

Just goto **admin>Store>Configuration>Customer Configuration>Login Options**.

And make **Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in**  select the value to **`No`**.Then flush the cache magento cache.

And see the magic

[image]

Comment: Its for login and working fine. I want the same thing for new registration.

Comment: this should work

Comment: It is working only in the case of sign in

Comment: I want the same thing for new registration.